# delete very big object in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

helo.
I'm new to c# and I got the big picture with GC deleting objects that can't be reached by my code. The problem new is that I'm working with some big (7-40 MB) objects , the good thing is that I don't need them all at once so is ther any posible way to delet an object?
I tried this:

```
- create big object X
- use big object X
  X = null; /*so I don't have any referance to it any more*/
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); - create next big object ....`
```

Does this guarantee that the big object will be deleted after the `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` exits?

I know that I should impromve my design to make the objects smaler but believe me I tried it and it makes the logic to complicated. If there is no other way I'll do it the the code will get 2 or 3 times bigger.

thanks!

Comment: why dont u just dispose the object using object.dispose();

Comment: @Ulhas: that assumes his object implements `IDisposable`; that might not even be necessary if it doesn't use streams or connections or other I/O stuff.

Comment: Disposing has nothing to do with garbage collection.

Comment: @ghet, what problem are you trying to solve? "My objects are big" is not a problem.

Comment: are you having memory leaks? what prompted you to look for a way to manually gc those objects?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid out of memory exception on pcs with les mem. if I do X = null; and then I create another bug object will the GC delete X (the object reference by) to make space for a nother one?

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to do this. Avoid calling `GC.Collect` manually. So if you don't need the objects at the same time, simply leave them out of scope and construct the new object. The garbage collector is smart enough and it will clean them when necessary. For example if you have plenty of free memory it might not bother but if memory starts running low it will collect them. It is highly optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Without mensioning your grammar skills, I would say there is no possible way to be 100% sure that the object gets deleted when you want it to.  
 The GC frees memory as it wants, calling GC.Collect does not free every object without a reference immediately. 
It does get deleted, but not at that point. Calling GC.Collect whitout knowing what it actually does is never a good idea! Leave it alone, GC knows what it does.

Comment: He's clearly not an native English speaker, so no need to take on his grammar skills, especially when you write *mentioning* as *mensioning*.

Comment: for the info I would give you a +1 but I don't have the rights , as for the language part try write somethig in Chinese maybe you'll do better then me in English;)

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `GC.Collect` manually. If you are not careful, you promote too many objects to generation 1 which will make them a lot more longer-lived.

In .NET, Microsoft's current implementation separates large objects (>84KB I believe) and they get managed separately.  Therefore, your large object will get garbage collected differently from normal objects, based on the garbage collector's algorithm (which changes from .NET version to .NET version).

Check this link for large object heap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, your link needs updating though. (5 years on) :-)

Answer (score 1):

pretty-much the only way to get ***a*** (singular) large object is to have a very large string or array (perhaps encapsulated inside a long list). Otherwise, you just have a large graph of small objects (many). Small objects aren't a problem; if it is no longer referenced, the GC will **at some point** clean it up, and compact the space (depending on the GC implementation).

If that isn't happening, then perhaps you have given out another reference to the graph - subscribing to an event is a classic way of doing this accidentally; as is adding one of the objects to a list that is still in play.
A single missed reference can keep a large graph from being collected, so watch that.

So far, the "fix" is simply; don't call GC; and check you don't have a missed reference.

A different problem, however, is when you have arras/strings that are large enough to go onto the "large object heap" (LOH). The LOH is not compacted, so you can hit problems with fragmentation here. One questionable way around that is to use a jagged array, i.e. 1,000 arrays of length 1,000 (plus an extra array to track them) instead of a single array of length 1,000,000 - YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Just one question: Have you had any problems with your code? Do the memory run out?

This feels like [premature optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211414/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)